# Is Joda-Time DateTimeFormatter class thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, jodatime, date-format

Is the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) `DateTimeFormatter` class [thread safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)? Once I get an instance from `DateTimeFormat.forPattern`, can its various parse methods be called by multiple threads? DateTimeFormatter's [Javadocs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) makes no mention of thread safety.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[Yes, it is](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

> DateTimeFormat is thread-safe and immutable, and the **formatters** it
>   returns are as well.

and so is the [Java 8 version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

> **Implementation Requirements:** This class is immutable and thread-safe.

Comment: And so is the Java8 one as well. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 14):

A quick look at the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.1/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.java#DateTimeFormatter) shows there isn't any mutable shared state in `DateTimeFormatter`, which would make it thread safe.

Comment: Nitpick: A quick look at the code does not necessarily show how the code will be changed in the next point release. It's always better to have an explicit guarantee in the documented API (of course, additionally checking the code cannot hurt).

Answer (score 5):

*Found this question on top of google's answers when checking for Java's java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter thread safety*

Java's own DateTimeFormatter is also thread-safe, as [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) states:

> This class is immutable and thread-safe